# Meaning and translation of 「佃煮にするほど」

Tags: translation, meaning

> のみこむのに苦労【くろう】した日本語【にほんご】は、佃煮【つくだに】にするほどあった。

According to the book explanation ほど is being used here to adduce an extreme example to metaphorically indicate the degree or severity of something. In this sentence, as I understand it, the writer is using 佃煮【つくだに】 (which I understand has a strong flavor) to indicate how hard it was to assimilate Japanese.

However I'm not sure if I got it right, I cannot quite explain or translate the sentence. I tried to look for other examples of the grammatical pattern on Internet but I couldn't find anything that could clarify the meaning of the sentence, I also looked at Wikipedia article for 佃煮【つくだに】 and I think the strong flavor of the food is the key here.

Comment: See http://lang-8.com/585068/journals/82092363745455775782689461865383173732.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The "large amount" is the key here, and the flavor of 佃煮 is not important. 佃煮 is a kind of preservative food, and it is made when we have too much food.

So "佃煮にするほどあった" here means "there were too many (Japanese expressions) which I couldn't digest/handle for now".

But this idiom is rare. The more common ways to metaphorically say "there are too many something (which are not particularly important)", are 「○○は星の数ほどある」, 「○○は掃いて捨てるほどある」, 「○○は腐るほどある」 etc.